# pass xml variable into c# method in xslt

Tags: xslt

i have xslt transform where im using c# code to save input and output xml to database.
but it saves only the values of all tags.
but i want to save vhole xml.

```
<msxsl:script language="CSharp" implements-prefix="ConnectDatabase">
          <msxsl:assembly name = "System.Data"/>
          <msxsl:using namespace = "System.Data"/>
          <msxsl:using namespace = "System.Data.SqlClient"/>
          <msxsl:using namespace = "System.Collections.Generic"/>

<![CDATA[      
   public void LogINOUT(string inputxml, string outputxml)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        string command = "INSERT INTO dbo.XsltLog (InputXml,OutputXml) VALUES (@inputxmlpar,@outputxmlpar)";
        string connectionString ="Data Source=MyConneCtionStiring;


        SqlParameter inputxmlpar = new SqlParameter("@inputxmlpar", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        inputxmlpar.Value=inputxml;
        SqlParameter outputxmlpar = new SqlParameter("@outputxmlpar", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        outputxmlpar.Value =outputxml;

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
          cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Format(command), connection);
          cmd.Parameters.Add(inputxmlpar);
          cmd.Parameters.Add(outputxmlpar);

            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }

   ]]></msxsl:script>
```

then a call it `<xsl:copy-of    select ="ConnectDatabase:LogINOUT( $inputxml,$outputxml)"  />`

and outputxml in database is something like this:
TO_TESTY45000.0000000020

from this string i know nothing
i wont its

```
<Data>
                            <Result>TO_TEST</Result>
                            <IncludeInVolume>Y</IncludeInVolume>
                            <FinancedAmont>
                                <xsl:value-of select="/Contract/ContractCalculations/Calculation/CalculationStep[@Code='FinancedAmount']"/>
                            </FinancedAmont>
                            <NumberOfInstalments>
                                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(/Contract/ContractCalculations/Calculation/CalculationStep[@Code='InstalmentNumber'],'#')"/>
                            </NumberOfInstalments>
                        </Data>
```

the same problem its with inputxml

thanks for Help Dana

Comment: Can you show us where you are defining `$inputXml` and `$outputXml`? Most likely you will need to change your method parameters to XPathNodeIterator and if you are dynamically building `$inputXml` and `$outputXml` in your XSLT, then you may need to do this: `ConnectDatabase:LogINOUT(msxsl:node-set($inputxml), msxsl:node-set($outputxml))`. I should also give you the usual caution that having functions with side-effects kind of violates the concepts of XSLT and it might be good to avoid.

Comment: im not happy of do side-effect function but my chef wont this functionality

Comment: input xml is `    name="inputxml" select="Contract"/>`

Comment: and ouptut xml i resolved like this ` <xsl:variable name="outputxml"><![CDATA[<Data><Result>APPROVED</Result><IncludeInVolume>Y</IncludeInVolume><FinancedAmont>]]><xsl:value-of select="/Contract/ContractCalculations/Calculation/CalculationStep[@Code='FinancedAmount']"/><![CDATA[ </FinancedAmont><NumberOfInstalments>]]><xsl:value-of select="format-number(/Contract/ContractCalculations/Calculation/CalculationStep[@Code='InstalmentNumber'],'#')"/><![CDATA[</NumberOfInstalments></Data>]]></neco>

Comment: but input xml is begger and isnt possible to do this like output

Comment: i have an error XSLT 1.0 Debugging Error: Error in XPath expression (Unknown function - Name and number of arguments do not match any function signature in the static context - 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt:node-set')
   `<xsl:copy-of    select ="ConnectDatabase:LogINOUT(msxsl:node-set($inputxml),$outputxml)"  />`   and signature of method is public void LogINOUT(System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator  inputxml, string outputxml)

Comment: hi    may be its because im working in xmlSPY,     in other posts its mentioned, that node-set is not working there    is some other way for xmlspy?